# Return table valued function return table structure like my actual table using Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table named tableincentive like below

```
create table tableincentive (entry_date date,ag_id int,us_id int,lo_id int,loin_id int,de_id int,dest_id int,incentive_amt decimal(18,2),le_id int,lion_id int,etc...)
```

And i have a table valued function named [dbo].[func_getdetails]

```
 Create FUNCTION [dbo].[func_getdetails]
    (
        -- Add the parameters for the function here
        @ason_date date
    )
    RETURNS 
    @tableincentive TABLE 
    (
        -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
        entry_date date,ag_id int,us_id int,lo_id int,loin_id int,de_id int,dest_id int,incentive_amt decimal(18,2),le_id int,lion_id int,etc...
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    -- some long process then
    insert into @tableincentive 
    select * from tableincentive;
    end
```

My problem is the table tableincentive has 43 columns so i create a table valued function return tableincentive structure.I need return like my actual table.
that means in function

```
     RETURNS 
            @tableincentive TABLE 
            (
                -- Add the column definitions for the TABLE variable here
                entry_date date,ag_id int,us_id int,lo_id int,loin_id int,de_id int,dest_id int,incentive_amt decimal(18,2),le_id int,lion_id int,etc...
            )
            AS
begin end
```

changed to

```
RETURNS  tableincentive
            AS
begin 
end
```

or

```
  RETURNS  @tableincentive table like tableincentive
                AS
    begin 
    end
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. when creating function, you should explicitly define the structure in RETURN clause

Comment: Can you use an inline table valued function? For multi statement ones you need to declare the definition.

Comment: @MartinSmith it is multi statement function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-defined functions need static results. That means you have to define the return type while creating the function. So If you want to have a static result set, then probably you should opt for a stored procedure.

Comment: I think you meant to say "if you want ... dynamic result set"